# Collections: How will you find the top 10 longest strings in a list of a billion strings?

Tags: string, data-structures, collections, comparator, treeset

I was recently asked a question in an interview. How will you find the top 10 longest strings in a list of a billion strings?
My Answer was that we need to write a Comparator that compares the lengths of 2 strings and then Use the TreeSet(Comparator) constructor.
Once you start adding the strings in the Treeset it will sort as per the sorting order of the comparator defined.
Then just pop the top 10 elements of the Treeset.

The Interviewer wasn't happy with that. The argument was that, to hold billion strings I will have to use a super computer.

Is there any other data stucture than can deal with this kind of data?

Comment: Read about this datastructure [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: Interviewer wanted to hear about priority queue (min-heap storing ten longest strings).

Answer (score 2):

Given what you stated about the interviewer saying you would need a super computer, I am going to assume that the strings would come in a stream one string at a time.

Given the immense size due to no knowledge of how large the individual strings are (they could be whole books), I would read them in one at a time from the stream. I would then compare the current string to an ordered list of the top ten longest strings found before it and place it accordingly in the ordered list. I would then remove the smallest length one from the list and proceed to read the next string. That would mean only 11 strings were being stored at one time, the current top 10 and the one currently being processed.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages have a built in sort that is pretty speedy.

```
stringList.sort(key=len)
```

in python would work. Then just grab the first 10 elements.

Also your interviewer does sounds behind the times. One billion strings is pretty small now a days

Answer (score 0):

I remember studying similar data structure for such scenarios called as [`Trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

The `height` of the `tree` will give the longest string always.

A special kind of trie, called a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), can be used to index all suffixes in a text in order to carry out fast full text searches.

Answer (score 0):

The point is you do not need to STORE all strings.

Let's think a simplified version: Find the longest 2 string (assuming no tie case)

You can always do a online algorithm like using 2 variables `s1` & `s2`, where `s1` is longest string you encountered so far, `s2` is the second longest

Then you use `O(N)` to read the strings one by one, replace `s1` or `s2` when it can.  This use `O(2N)` = `O(N)`

For top 10 strings, it is as dumb as the top 2 case.  You can still do it in `O(10N)` = `O(N)` and store only 10 strings.

There is a faster way describe as follow but for given constant like 2 or 10, you may not need it.

---

For top-K strings in general, you can use structure like `set` in C++ (with longer having higher priority) to store the top-K strings, when a new string comes, you simply insert it, and remove the last one, both use `O(lg K)`. So total you can do it in `O(N lg K)` with `O(K)` space.